# How do I set delegate = self when I only want communication from one controller to the other

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a LoginController() that is being presented from MainController(). So technically MainController() is still loaded and in memory in the background. Now in LoginController(), when I press the login button, I want to notify the MainController() that login button is pressed so fetch the current user again. Then I dismiss LoginController().

I want to do this with protocols and delegates but problem is when MainController() conforms to LoginDelegate, I do not know how to set delegate to self. Because when a user logs out or if there is no user, I do not want to go back to login controller, I want to go back to a different WelcomeController(). If I wanted to go to LoginController() then I know I can do

```
let loginController = LoginController()
loginController.delegate = self
self.present(loginController)
```

But in my case, I want to go to a completely different controller. So where do I set the delegate to self?

Here is the code:

```
//LoginController()
protocol LoginDelegate {
    func didTapLogIn()
}

class LoginController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

    var loginDelegate: LoginDelegate!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureViews()
        formValidation()
    }

    @objc func handleLogin(){
        guard let email = emailTextField.text else {return}
        guard let password = passwordTextField.text else {return}
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (auth, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print("There was a problem signing the user in", error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            self.loginDelegate.didTapLogIn()
            print("Successfully signed in the user")
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the MainController that conforms

```
//MainController() which is a tab bar controller

class MainController: UITabBarController, LoginDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkLoggedInUserStatus()
    }

    fileprivate func checkLoggedInUserStatus(){
        if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let welcomeController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: WelcomeController())
                welcomeController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                self.present(welcomeController, animated: false, completion: nil)
                return
            }
        } else {
            setupTabBar()
        }
    }

    fileprivate func setupTabBar(){
        tabBar.isTranslucent = false
        tabBar.barTintColor = TDGOtherBlue

        let homeController = HomeController()
        homeController.fetchCurrentUser()
        let homeViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeController)
    let chatViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: EditProfileController())

        viewControllers = [homeViewController, chatViewController]
    }

    func didTapLogIn() {
        checkLoggedInUserStatus()
    }
}
//NOTE: ABOVE IS THE DELEGATED FUNCTION BUT WHERE DO I DO THE DELEGATE SELF DECLARATIOn
```

Comment: Delegation is something have to be done between `view` and `controller`. You should use **Notification** for this scenario instead.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Delegation is a pretty reasonable choice here. Notifications are best reserved for loosely coupled objects, e.g. when the sender and receiver(s) might not even know about each other.

Comment: Consider that in a storyboard environment the default initializer `LoginController()` doesn't work at all. And in Swift basically callback closures are more efficient than protocol / delegate.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for your comment. Thing is I am new to swift and I have not used storyboards since the start. Was coached doing things programmatically. Care to elaborate what you mean here?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I did think of notification and observers but the observer would be sitting on a tab controller until deinit so don't you think that is unnecessary when I simply want the login controller to tell the main controller that 'hey login button is pressed'?

Answer (score 1):

Notes:

Your architecture looks like a cocktail.
But, nonetheless, notes:

```
weak var loginDelegate: LoginDelegate? // should be weak and optional
```

Use this flow:

```
            self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.loginDelegate.didTapLogIn()
            print("Successfully signed in the user")
}
```

You didn't describe what is `Auth`,

some you cannot be guaranteed that

`Auth.auth().currentUser` is not actually nil

even inside here:

```
@objc func handleLogin(){
//....
Auth.auth().signIn( ... {
///here
/// check it!
})
```

So, if not, use

```
protocol LoginDelegate {
    func didTapLogIn(user: User)
}
```

instead

**EDIT**

Obviously, if you have nothing more while LoginViewController is being closed, you can send the data into AppDelegate.

```
final class AppDelegate: UIResponder {
}
extension AppDelegate: LoginDelegate { ... }
```

To retrieve AppDelegate shared instance you can use:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

The second solution, you can obtain your view controller using AppDelegate. This way:

```
let rootViewController = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController
```

Comment: You are right 'LoginDelegate' should be weak and optional but defining it as weak requires making protocol LoginDelegate : **NSObjectProtocol**

Comment: @AmjadTubasi no. You just can use 'protocol LoginDelegate: class'. I forgot, sorry

Comment: @Vyacheslav Those are some useful tips. The problem is not the checking itself. The problem is that my app delegate has set MainController as the rootViewController of the window. So for the first time, when a user installs the app and tries to login, the maincontroller obviously has no value since it loaded itself during app launch. LoginController is just being presented on top so I need a way for loginController to tell mainController that 'you need to fetch the new logged in user'. Problem is my maincontroller is not linked to loginController. So I don't know where to set login delegate

Comment: @Vyacheslav : interesting. Will try this out

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know how to set delegate to self. Because when a user logs out or if there is no user, I do not want to go back to login controller, I want to go back to a different WelcomeController().

It sounds like MainController is really running the show. You haven't said much about WelcomeController, but it sounds like the flow is something like this:

1. App starts up, creates and displays MainController.
2. If MainController doesn't have a user, it creates and displays a WelcomeController.
3. User taps some button in WelcomeController indicating he/she wants to log in. WelcomeController sends a message to MainController telling it to start the login process, then gets dismissed.
4. MainController creates a LoginController and displays it.
5. LoginController gets the user's credentials, sends them to MainController, and then gets dismissed.
6. At some point the user logs out, at which point there is no user, so go to step 2.

So the answer would be that MainController sets itself as LoginController's delegate in step 4, somewhere between creating and displaying LoginController.

Comment: That's right. MainController is set as the rootcontroller in app delegate. WelcomeController has some nice graphics and has two buttons that point to loginController and signupcontroller. Just one correction: User taps log in button in login controller and login controller asks the mainController to reload and fetch the current user details. WelcomeController is just an aesthetic controller that points to the login and sign up controller. So flow is: Welcome -> login -> Main & Main(if logout pressed) -> welcome

Answer (score 0):

You need to to assign delegate value from prepare function. Or you can assign delegate with initialize RedScreenVC(self) from your ViewController if u don't want to use storyboard/xib.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, NavDelegate {
    func navigate(text: String, isShown: Bool) {
        print("text: \(text) isShown: \(isShown)")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "RedScreenVC") {
            let redScreenVC = segue.destination as? RedScreenVC
            redScreenVC?.delegate = self
        }
    }

    @IBAction func nextPageButtonEventLustener(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "RedScreenVC", sender: sender)
    }
}



import UIKit

protocol NavDelegate {
    func navigate(text: String, isShown: Bool)
}
class RedScreenVC: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: NavDelegate?

    var redView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))

    var navigateButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 350, width: 150, height: 50))
        button.setTitle("Navigate", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        return button
    }()

    @objc func buttonAction(){
        if self.redView.backgroundColor == .gray {
            self.redView.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        }
    self.delegate.navigate(text:"", isShown: true)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        navigateButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        redView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

        delegate.navigate(text: "Navigation Success", isShown: true)

        view.addSubview(redView)

        view.addSubview(navigateButton)
    }

}
```

If you do not want to use storyboard and initialize as like

let redScreenVC = RedScreenVC()

redScreenVC.delegate = self

```
class RedScreenVC: UIViewController {
  override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

init() {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.initialize()
}

func initialize() {
    self.view.backgroundColor=CustomColor.PAGE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_1
    //From here you need to create your email and password textfield
}
}
```

Comment: Thing is I just noticed in your example, the problem is that I will not be going to RedScreenVC from anywhere in my ViewController.  My question if you see above is how do I set delegate when I am not referencing the controller that has the protocol

Comment: you can not initialize as like LoginController()

Answer (score 0):

```
let vc = FirstViewController.instantiate(fromStoryboard: .Profile)
    vc.callback = { (address, lat, lon) in
        self.updateLocation(address: address ?? "", lat: lat ?? 0.0, lon: lon ?? 0.0)
    }
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Then in secondVC

```
var callback : (( address: String?, latitude: Double?,_ longitude: Double?)-> Void)!
```

Then when you want to pass the value back to previous VC, in click or dismiss event add.

```
callback(address,Double(lat),Double(lon))
```